# STM32 HAL I2C IsDeviceReady (I2C detect) device Plug out and Plug in again - No Device found

Tags: stm32, i2c, hal

I am implementing I2C detect feature in my stm32 ptoject, but I came across a problem. I am using stm32F103C8T6 (BluePill) and Nucloe-144 board which shows the same behavior.

**The problem:**
When I'm running i2cdetect function in loop with some delay (3-5 sec) I can see the address of my i2c slave device (e.g. MCP23008), but if I plug connector out (4pin connector = gnd,scl,sda,vcc at the same time) and then plug it in again I can't see the device until I reset I2C master (bluepill or nucleo).
**Note:** I can plug out and plug in again i2c slaves as many times as I want and I will see them every time I use the i2cdetect command from i2ctools with my raspberry pi 3 model B.

My i2cmaster **code** implementing i2cdetect:

```
int main(void)
{
while (1)
  {
      i2c_detect();
      HAL_Delay(5000);
  }
}

void i2c_detect(void)
{
    char str[56];   uint8_t len=0;  uint8_t devices = 0, ret;
    extern I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

    CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)"\r\nSearching for I2C devices on the bus...\r\n", strlen("\r\nSearching for I2C devices on the bus...\r\n"));

    for (uint8_t i = 1; i < 128; i++)
    {
        ret = HAL_I2C_IsDeviceReady(&hi2c1, (uint8_t)(i<<1), 3, 10);
        if (ret != HAL_OK) /* No ACK Received At That Address */
        {
        while (USBD_BUSY == CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)" - ", strlen(" - ")));

        }
        else if (ret == HAL_OK)
        {
            len=sprintf(str,"0x%X",i);
            while (USBD_BUSY == CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)str, len));
            devices++;
        }
    }
    /* Feedback of the total number of devices. */
    if (devices == 0)
    {
        while (USBD_BUSY == CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)"\r\nNo device found.", strlen("\r\nNo device found.")));
    }
    else
    {
        len=sprintf(str,"\r\nTotal found devices: %d",devices);
        while (USBD_BUSY == CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)str, len));
    }
}
```

So, any thoughts why this happening? How can I implement behavior same to i2cdetect from i2ctools on Linux?

Comment: I think when you plug in/out, some voltages jump on the I2C line or some other significant noise happens, and there is probably a frame error in I2C peripheral. Try pausing execution and looking at I2C status registers. Or clearing I2C register entirely for starters.